# Rotate PDFs using iText and org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

i'm working with iText in Java Servlets. I'm fighting with the creation of PDFs from my JSP files. I've seen that is not possible, so i created new servlets which parse a String (my HTML page). Here part of the code:

```
StringBuffer buffer = getHTMLinBuffer(consulenti, anUser);
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
String fileName = "listaConsulenti.pdf";
String absolutePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
String tempPath = absolutePath + "temp/";
File file = new File(tempPath, fileName);
file.createNewFile();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
os.close();
```

This code works.
Now i have to create another PDF which needs to have an A4 page rotated by 90°. Using org.w3c.dom.Document i can't find how to do.
There is the possibility to use another Document Class, the **com.itextpdf.text.Document** which has the rotate() method to rotate it, but using this Document i can't find how to do to parse my String (HTML code)...

Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...i've just found out, that iTextRendere is not part of iText, but of Flying Source. 
In [this link](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/10/31/combine-facelets-and-flying-saucer-renderer.html) i've seen that the creation of a landscape page is simply done by adding some css to the source (X)HTML:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
@page{ size: 11.69in 8.27in;}
...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a document on it's side, you can use the following:

```
private Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
```

Comment: No i can't. Using org.w3c.dom.Document it is not possible.